# Send invoice by email through Zoho Books API

Tags: php, api, email, cakephp-2.0, zohobooks

My Code is as follows...

**The email functions**

```
public function zoho_email($array){
$data = json_decode($array,true);       
                $url = '/invoices/'.$data['invoice']['invoice_id'].'/email';
                $recivers[] =   array($data['invoice']['contact_persons_details'][0]['email']);
                $data = array(
                    'to_mail_ids'               => $recivers,
                    'subject'                   => 'Invoice from MSL (Invoice#: '.$data['invoice']['invoice_number'].')',
                    'body'                      => 'Dear Customer,<br><br><br><br>Thanks for your business,
                    'send_from_org_email_id'    => true
                );      
                $result = $this->zoho_create($url, $data);

            }
```

**The curl Function for create invoices, contacts, and send email**

```
        public function zoho_create($url,$array){   
                $json = json_encode($array);
                $data = array('authtoken' => ZOHOAUTHTOKEN,'JSONString' => $json,'organization_id'  => ZOHOORGNISATIONID);
                $curl = curl_init($this->apiUrl.$url);
                if($url=='contacts/'){
                    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
                    ));
                }
                else{
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); 
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded") );          
                }
                $response = curl_exec($curl);
                curl_close($curl);
                return $response;
            }
```

I want to send invoice by email through API to customer but This error occur in my code.

> {"code":5,"message":"Invalid URL Passed"}

Please help me out there....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working correctly. Try to print the url (`$url`) and confirm once if it is in the required format (`/invoices/invoice_id/email`). For example if your invoice_id is 1234, then the `$url` should be '`/invoices/1234/email`'. Also make sure that `$this->apiUrl` is `https://books.zoho.com/api/v3`

If there occurs a problem still u can use the help documents mentioned below:

https://www.zoho.com/books/api/v3/.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using full url : "https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/invoices/:invoiceno/email"